# displaytag element repositioning with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, displaytag

Quick question.  I am using the the jquery.easytabs plugin along with the displaytag library to display a bunch of tables in separate tabs.

What I would like to do is move the export links div to the top of each table.  I thought it would be easy to do with jquery and tried this.

```
$('.exportlinks').prev().before($('.exportlinks'));
```

But this is showing the export links for each tab in every tab.

Each tab content div has a unique id, but the exportlinks div's have identical classes.

I hope this is making sense, I'm sure there's a clever way to do this... Please help!

Thanks,
Vance

Comment: Can you give an example of the DOM so those that aren't familiar with the structure required for those specific plugins can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will be better to see the dom, but you can  try this :

> $('.exportlinks:last').prev().before($('.exportlinks:first'));